# Whether a matrix of the kind $A+\sqrt{-1}\cdot B$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Let $A_0=(a_{ij})_{N\times N}$ be a real symmetric matrix. Now denote the following two real symmetric matrices by
$$
A=\left(\cos{\frac{(i+j)\pi}{2m}}\cdot a_{ij}\right)_{N\times N},\,\,\,B=\left(\sin{\frac{(i+j)\pi}{2m}}\cdot a_{ij}\right)_{N\times N},
$$
where $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Suppose that both $A$ and $B$ are invertible.
Can we prove that the complex matrix $A+\sqrt{-1}\cdot B$ is also invertible?

Since $B$ is invertible, thus it's equvivalent to prove that $\sqrt{-1}\cdot I+AB^{-1}$ is invertible. If $AB^{-1}$ is symmetic (which is  equvivalent to $AB=BA$ ), then its eigenvalues are all real, and the proof ends. However, in our case we don't have $AB=BA$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counterexample. Let
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \cr 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},\; 
B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Both $A$ and $B$ are real, symmetric, invertible matrices. However,
$$
A+iB=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & i \cr i & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
has determinant zero, so is not invertible.

Comment: I assume that B is symmetric, not anti-symmetric.

Comment: Actually, this is also the first "counterexample" came up in my mind.

Comment: @Tomas Ah, I did not read that the matrices should be symmetric (it says "Suppose that both $A$ and $B$ are invertible. ). I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

No. E.g. consider $m=1$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
A_0&=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1},\\
C&=\left(\cos\frac{(i+j)\pi}{2}\right)_{i,j\in\{1,2\}}=\pmatrix{-1&0\\ 0&1},\\
S&=\left(\sin\frac{(i+j)\pi}{2}\right)_{i,j\in\{1,2\}}=\pmatrix{0&-1\\ -1&0},\\
A&=C\circ A_0=C,\\
B&=S\circ A_0=S,\\
A+\mathbf iB&=C+\mathbf i S=\pmatrix{-1&-\mathbf i\\ -\mathbf i&1}=\pmatrix{1\\ \mathbf i}\pmatrix{-1&-\mathbf i}.\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thanks. I see that the main reason is that $A_0$ may be singular